# Replacing a varchar FK with a new Int FK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have two tables which we will call Event and EventResponse

- `Event` has PK `eventGuid varchar(36)` and several other columns
- `EventResponse` has FK `eventGuid varchar(36)` and other columns

I can easily add an `INT identity` column to `Event` with:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Event]
   ADD eventId INT IDENTITY;
```

And adding a column to `EventResponse` table is Ok.

How do I update all the eventIds in the response table?

Is this possible with a neat query or do I have to loop through?

Final state should be:

- `Event` has PK `eventId, eventGuid varchar(36)`, other columns
- `EventResponse` has `FK eventId, eventGuid varchar(36)`, other columns

Comment: What do want to update in the newly created column eventId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No looping required. Words to live by :)

This should be just about all you need. Use your existing foreign key to update the values for your new key, then drop the old relationship and add the new one.

```
UPDATE er
  SET er.eventID = e.eventID
FROM
  dbo.EventResponse AS er
  JOIN
  dbo.Event as e
    ON er.eventGuid = e.eventGuid;

GO 

ALTER TABLE dbo.EventResponse
DROP CONSTRAINT <FK_Name> 

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.EventResponse
ADD CONSTRAINT <FK_Name> FOREIGN KEY (eventId)
  REFERENCES dbo.Event(eventId)
  [ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE]

GO
```

Then, probably, if you want to save some space in your database:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Event
DROP COLUMN eventGuid;

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.EventResponse
DROP COLUMN eventGuid;

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
update a set a.eventId=b.eventId
from EventResponse a
inner join Event b on a.eventGuid = b.eventGuid
```